# How to inject Cache Manager in My Custom Provider

Tags: node.js, nestjs

I try to use cache-manager in my nestjs web app.

In my Module I register my Cache

```
@Module({
    imports: [
        _CacheModule.register(),
    ],
})
export class CacheModule {}
```

From the same mudule I have another custom provider which need to inject CacheManager.

```
import {Cache} from '@nestjs/common'
...

async function providerFactory(
    config: Config,
    cache: Cache,
    logger: Logger,
): Promise<Store> {
    return process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'
        ? new StoreA(keyValueConfig, cache, logger)
        : new StoreB(keyValueConfig, logger);
}

export const RedisOrMockKeyValueStoreProvider: Provider = {
    provide: Store,
    useFactory: providerFactory,
    inject: [Config, Cache, Logger],
};
```

But I got *Cache is not defined* Error when the app start. How should I inject the cache into my custom provider?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [`CACHE_MANAGER`](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/caching#interacting-with-the-cache-store) injection token instead of `Cache`

Comment: Thanks, @jay-mcdoniel. where should i put the injection token, the factory funtion or the proviver inject?

Comment: In the `inject`

Comment: Hey @JayMcDoniel I've added into `inject` array with my CacheModule previously imported but is not accesible yet into the provider function.. Any thoughts?

Comment: @JoseAngelPeñarrocheDelgadounsure without see an error or current setup